# Error creating bean in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i created an app based on spring boot and spring boot data , so i want to use

HSQLDB in memory

This is my Application Class :

```
package boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication()
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Config.class);

    }

}
```

and this is Config class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller", "dao", "service"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
class Config {


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

}
```

as you khnow in the these three packages "controller", "dao", "service" there are 
some @Autowired

when i run the Application, i got this error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'taskController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private service.TaskManager controller.TaskController.taskManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskManagerImpl' defined in file [D:\JavaSe\restAng\target\classes\service\impl\TaskManagerImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

this is my TaskController

```
@RestController
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskManager taskManager;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/tasks", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        return taskManager.getAll();
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it ?

Comment: According to the logs, you are missing some dependecy: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable]`

Comment: Can you please share your TaskController and TaskManagerImpl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing aspectjweaver. You need to add it to your dependencies.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```